# A question about the proof of Cauchy criterion for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

**Theorem 2.6.4** in `Understanding Analysis` by Abbott states,
$\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$

> A sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence.

$(\rightarrow)$ direction.

This direction has already been established earlier.

$(\leftarrow)$ direction.

[image]

---

Strictly speaking, wouldn't it be the case that,

(1) $\exists N_1$, such that the distance $\lvert x_n - x_m \rvert$ can be made smaller than $\epsilon/2$ for all $m,n \ge N_1$. That is,

\begin{align*}
   \lvert {x_n - x_m} \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}

for all $m,n \ge N_1$

(2) $\exists N_2$, such that the distance $\lvert x_{n_k} - x\rvert$ can be made smaller than $\epsilon/2$ for all $n_{k} \ge N_2$:

\begin{align*}
   \lvert {x_{n_k} - x} \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}

Choose a fixed term $x_{n_K}$ in the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, so that $n_K \ge N_2$.

Let $N = \max \{N_1,N_2\}$. To see that $N$ has the desired property (for the original sequence $(x_n)$), observe that if $n \ge N$, then

\begin{align*}
    \absval{x_n - x} &= \absval{x_n - x_{n_K} + x_{n_K} - x}\\
     &\le  \absval{x_n - x_{n_K}} + \absval{x_{n_K} - x}\\
     &< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon
\end{align*}

Is the minor detail of choosing $N = \max \{N_1,N_2\}$ ommitted and implicit in the textbook proof? Or this isn't required.

Comment: did you get the directions reversed perhaps?

Comment: @BCLC, edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Guys, you know what, the proof in the book makes sense to me now, upon reading it carefully again! :) Cheers, thanks.